# vimrc is not the ultimate configuration file

Tags: vimrc

I have to make explicit source file, eg:

```
vim -S ~/.vimrc whatever.md
```

otherwise it's either ignored or superseded by other configuration files.

I've found running with strace the following order in which is such a directories/files are read:

Edited according comment from muru (using :scriptnames):

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/synload.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syncolor.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/ftdetect/stp.vim
  7: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin.vim
  8: ~/.vimrc
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 10: /usr/share/vim/vim74/ftoff.vim
 11: ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
 12: ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
 13: ~/.vim/plugin/acp.vim
 14: ~/.vim/autoload/acp.vim
 15: ~/.vim/plugin/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 16: ~/.vim/plugin/plugin/clam.vim
 17: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-fugitive/plugin/fugitive.vim
 18: ~/.vim/bundle/L9/plugin/l9.vim
 19: ~/.vim/bundle/L9/autoload/l9.vim
 20: ~/.vim/bundle/command-t/plugin/command-t.vim
 21: ~/.vim/bundle/tabular/plugin/Tabular.vim
 22: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 23: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/gzip.vim
 24: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/logiPat.vim
 25: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/matchparen.vim
 26: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 27: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 28: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/spellfile.vim
 29: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 30: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/tohtml.vim
 31: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 32: /usr/share/vim/vim74/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 33: ~/.vim/bundle/tabular/after/plugin/TabularMaps.vim
 34: ~/.vim/bundle/tabular/autoload/tabular.vim
```

My config file is:

```
syntax on
set background=dark
set tabstop=3
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'L9'
Plugin 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}
Plugin 'godlygeek/tabular'
Plugin 'plasticboy/vim-markdown'
call vundle#end()            " required
ab animr {:&.rollIn}
ab animm {:&.moveIn}
ab animz {:&.zoomIn}
ab animf {:&.fadeIn}
ab animb {:&.bounceIn}
ab s[ [slide]
let g:vim_markdown_folding_disabled = 1
```

The version of vim is 7.4 and the Operating System is Fedora 23.

Any ideas about this behaviour?

Comment: Instead of running `strace`, use `:scriptnames`. Why does the `strace` output show `/home/sergio/.vimrc/` with a trailing slash, as if it were a directory? And `-S` is for restoring a session, not loading a vimrc. The option for setting a vimrc is `-u`: `vim -u ~/.vimrc`, for example.

Comment: Respect trailing slash, it was a typo, regarding `-S` my man page it says: `-S {file}   {file}  will  be  sourced  after  the  first  file has been read.  This is equivalent to -c "source {file}".  {file} cannot start with '-'.  If {file} is omitted "Session.vim"  is  used  (only  works when -S is the last argument).`

Comment: Use Vim normally to make it work normally: `$ vim` or `$ vim .` or `$ vim filename` or `$ vim *.ext`.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This has all the signs of being an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/166789).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is by mistake, I've deleted the following line:

```
filetype plugin indent on    " required
```

That line goes right after:

```
call vundle#end()            " required
```

Explanation from vim documentation about `filetype plugin indent`:

```
You can enable loading the indent file for specific file types with:
        :filetype indent on
If filetype detection was not switched on yet, it will be as well.
This actually loads the file "indent.vim" in 'runtimepath'.
The result is that when a file is edited its indent file is loaded (if there
is one for the detected filetype). indent-expression
```